# as.integer is not working with aggregate and multiple functions

Tags: r, aggregate

I am trying to use `aggregate` to get count and mean of weight by group where I want to show count as integer and mean as double.

Following code works well:

```
> aggregate(weight~group, data=PlantGrowth, FUN=function(x) as.integer(length(x)))
  group weight
1  ctrl     10
2  trt1     10
3  trt2     10
```

But length gets converted to double in following code:

```
> aggregate(weight~group, data=PlantGrowth, FUN=function(x) c(len=length(x), mn=mean(x)))
  group weight.len weight.mn
1  ctrl     10.000     5.032
2  trt1     10.000     4.661
3  trt2     10.000     5.526
```

Even `as.integer` does not work:

```
> aggregate(weight~group, data=PlantGrowth, FUN=function(x) c(len=as.integer(length(x)), mn=mean(x)))
  group weight.len weight.mn
1  ctrl     10.000     5.032
2  trt1     10.000     4.661
3  trt2     10.000     5.526
```

How can I get integer values of length with aggregate and multiple functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `aggregate` returns a `data.frame` with a nested `matrix` of your summary statistics `mean` and `length` (take a look at `str(your_aggregate_return_object)`.

You can ensure proper casting by doing:

```
agg <- aggregate(weight~group, data=PlantGrowth, FUN=function(x) c(len=length(x), mn=mean(x)));
do.call(data.frame, agg);
```

Comment: Can you please explain what does the `do.call` do here? How is `do.call` different from just calling a function?

Comment: `do.call(data.frame, ...)` applies a function (here `data.frame`) to the columns of your `aggregate` return object, thereby doing all the implicit data type castings that `data.frame` usually does when you construct a new `data.frame`.

Comment: @doviod Perhaps a (cleaner?) alternative would be to use `dplyr::summarise` to construct new aggregate statistics. In that case you can avoid the extra `do.call(data.frame, ...)` call because of the way that `tibble`s handle data types.

Comment: @MauritsEvers thanks, but why doesn't `data.frame(agg)` achieve the same thing?

Comment: @doviod `data.frame(agg)` casts the entire object as a `data.frame` (which it already is, so there's nothing to do here); `do.call(data.frame, ...)` re-builds the `data.frame` column-by-column. It's as if you were writing out `data.frame(group = agg$group, ...)`, where `data.frame` infers data types from each individual column.